# Is it possible to predict protein-ligand binding kinetics using machine learning?

Tags: proteins, machine-learning, interactions

I would like to work on a project that involves the prediction of protein-ligand binding kinetics. What might be the feature that is relevant for the prediction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the current state-of-the-art in protein-ligand binding affinity prediction using machine learning?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/what-is-the-current-state-of-the-art-in-protein-ligand-binding-affinity-predicti)

Comment: Anyway, yes but you need access to a large database of experimental daa for protein-ligand affinity binding for training and validation. In addition, you'll need to vectorise the ligands ... which may not be at all easy. Personally, I would update your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a comment to redirect to other answers, but go too long.

Docking is the *in silico* prediction of where a ligand binds in a protein.

There are several Q&As about docking here that are relevant, so please check out:

- machine learning, docking and the factors that affect it: [Generate ligands candidates based on protein shape](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/12971/generate-ligands-candidates-based-on-protein-shape/12975#12975) —also worth a read the ["learning from the ligand" paper](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article-abstract/36/3/758/5554651) paper, which discusses why some ligand only parameters tell a lot about binding.
- correlation between docking scores and enzyme kinetics: [Purpose of correlating docking score with catalytic efficiency(Kcat/km)](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7504/purpose-of-correlating-docking-score-with-catalytic-efficiencykcat-km/10593#10593) —discusses a paper https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms12965 wherein a linear regression is done between docking scores and kcat/KM